# MonoMac: NsView and System.Drawing.Graphics

Tags: .net, mono, system.drawing, monomac

I'm trying to get a .NET 4.0-application to work under Mac with MonoMac.

Unfortunately I need System.Drawing.Graphics at some point.
I find a lot about using System.Drawing with a NsView if I google it, but nothing which works when it comes to System.Drawing.Graphics.

If I do it the way I'd do it with my WinForms-Knowledge, I end up with this piece of code:

```
using (var g = Graphics.FromHwnd (this.TheNsViewInstance.Handle))
{
    g.DrawRectangle (new Pen(Color.Green), new Rectangle (new Point(50, 50), new Size (100, 50)));
}
```

But then my application breaks with a **System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException**.

On the mono-github, I found some examples where they create a Graphics-Instance with 0 arguments ([for example here](https://github.com/mono/sysdrawing-coregraphics/blob/master/Samples/MonoMac/Example2_2/DrawingView.cs)). But if I do that, I can't compile because with the Mono-Assemblies I have there is no Graphics with a "0 Parameters"-constructor (I reference the same as they did in the example).

If anybody knows what's possibly wrong - or can provide another example, I'd really appreciate it.

I'm runnning the latest stable release of mono (2.10.11).

Thank you very much!

Comment: You know that the file you linked is not a standalone example, right? It's part of a bigger project, which provides System.Drawing functionality on top of CoreGraphics. That's where the Graphics object with 0 parameters-constructor probably comes from...

Answer (score 1):

Just Create the empty constructor and IntPtr constructor and it should work afterwards. Cocoa needs those to instantiate the objects.

```
public MyControl(){}
public MyControl (IntPtr handle) : base (handle) {}
```